# How to pass additional variables with Apollo Client 3?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, graphql-codegen

I'm trying to pass additional variables in my client (apollo 3) like this:

```
MY_QUERY = gql`
  mutation MyMutation {
    my_mutation {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`
```

```
client.query({
  query: MY_QUERY,
  variables: {
   extra_variable: 1,
   extra_variable: 2
  }
})
```

This doesn't work on apollo 3. But on Apollo 2 it works. Am I forgetting any settings? Or is it no longer possible?

Context: graphql generator for react.

Comment: why it should be possible?

Comment: I have to pass the default "account_id" argument for all queries and mutations. If it is not possible in Apollo 3, I will need to change all files (too many) to insert this argument as needed. So, it is not possible in 3?

Comment: use link to pass custom header

Comment: Yes. It is an alternative, but I was wondering if it would be possible to allow this with some configuration or flag in Apollo setup. I believe that it is not possible. Anyway thank you.